# Finding e-commerce site of the product URL given and see if it is supported

Tags: python, url

I am building a Python app in which user can maintain wishlist of the products. I only support few e-commerce sites and do not support country specific sites (e.g I may support amazon.com but not amazon.in). I do not support mobile version of the URL (e.g. http://m.amazon.com) and also I am not interested in the query string part of the URL (and I don't want it also).

Following is the code and also the test cases. Though it seems to be working, I am not happy with the code. It looks hackish to me. I would really appreciate improving `get_vendor` function. Do you find it readable?

```
from urlparse import urlparse

supported_vendors = ['flipkart.com', 'homeshop18.com', 'snapdeal.com', 
                    'myntra.com', 'www.flipkart.com', 'www.homeshop18.com', 
                    'www.snapdeal.com', 'www.myntra.com']

test_urls =['http://www.myntra.com/sports-shoes/puma/puma-men-grey-kuris-ii-ind-running-shoes/107455/buy?searchQuery=sports-shoes&serp=1&uq=false#!',
            'www.myntra.com/sports-shoes/puma/puma-men-grey-kuris-ii-ind-running-shoes/107455/buy?searchQuery=sports-shoes&serp=1&uq=false#!',
            'https://myntra.com/sports-shoes/puma/puma-men-grey-kuris-ii-ind-running-shoes/107455/buy?searchQuery=sports-shoes&serp=1&uq=false#!',
            'http://.myntra.com/sports-shoes/puma/puma-men-grey-kuris-ii-ind-running-shoes/107455/buy?searchQuery=sports-shoes&serp=1&uq=false#!',
            'htt://www.myntra.com/sports-shoes/puma/puma-men-grey-kuris-ii-ind-running-shoes/107455/buy?searchQuery=sports-shoes&serp=1&uq=false#!',
            'http://blahblah.com/sports-shoes/puma/puma-men-grey-kuris-ii-ind-running-shoes/107455/buy?searchQuery=sports-shoes&serp=1&uq=false#!',
            'ftp://myntra.com/sports-shoes/puma/puma-men-grey-kuris-ii-ind-running-shoes/107455/buy?searchQuery=sports-shoes&serp=1&uq=false#!']

test_expected_results = [True, True, True, False, False, False, False]

def get_vendor(url):
    def add_http(url):
        return 'http://'+url

    def get_url(parsed_url):
        return 'http://'+parsed_url.netloc+parsed_url.path

    if not urlparse(url).scheme:
        parsed_url = urlparse(add_http(url))
    elif urlparse(url).scheme not in ['http', 'https']:
        return (None, url)
    else:
        parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    if parsed_url.netloc not in supported_vendors:
        return (None, url)
    else:
        return (parsed_url.netloc, get_url(parsed_url))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # for i in map(get_vendor, test_urls):
    #     print i
    assert(map(lambda x: bool(x[0]), map(get_vendor, test_urls)) == test_expected_results)
```

based on what vendor returns I apply different scraping functions. Here is the next code:

```
HS18 = ['homeshop18.com', 'www.homeshop18.com']
SD = ['snapdeal.com', 'www.snapdeal.com']
FS = ['flipkart.com', 'www.flipkart.com']
MYN = ['myntra.com', 'www.myntra.com']

vendor, url = get_vendor(url)

if not vendor:
    exit # or throw error

product_doc = search_for_url_in_database(url)

if not product_doc:
    if vendor in FS:
        product_url, product_name, product_img_url, product_price = get_flipkart_product_meta(url)
    elif vendor in HS18:
        product_url, product_name, product_img_url, product_price = get_homeshop18_product_meta(url)
    elif vendor in SD:
        product_url, product_name, product_img_url, product_price = get_snapdeal_product_meta(url)
    else:
        product_url, product_name, product_img_url, product_price = get_myntra_product_meta(url)

...
```

This last if block I can change it to:

```
if not product_doc:
    if vendor in FS:
        get_product_meta = get_flipkart_product_meta
    elif vendor in HS18:
        get_product_meta = get_homeshop18_product_meta
    elif vendor in SD:
        get_product_meta = get_snapdeal_product_meta
    else:
        get_product_meta = get_myntra_product_meta
    product_url, product_name, product_img_url, product_price = get_product_meta(url)

...
```

1. What do you say about this second `if` block where I am assigning function object to a variable and calling it later. Should I be doing like this? What's the suggested way?
2. The lists defined at top, has redundant data. Is there any way to make it better?
3. I really would like to keep leading `www` if the url has (even though avoiding this do not harm). So how do I do this with cleaner way? or you suggest to remove `www` completely?

Generally how do you guys handle situation like this, when you have to call a function based on if-else blocks?

**EDIT**: Following code was suggested by someone on reddit. Looks clean to me:

```
PRODUCT_METAS = {
    'homeshop18.com': get_homeshop18_product_meta,
    'snapdeal.com': get_snapdeal_product_meta,
    'flipkart.com': get_flipkart_product_meta,
   ' myntra.com': get_myntra_product_meta,
}

vendor, url = get_vendor(url)
if vendor is None:
    exit()

product_doc = search_for_url_in_database(url)

if not product_doc:
    if vendor.startswith('www.'):
        vendor = vendor[len('www.'):]
    try:
        product_url, product_name, product_img_url, product_price = PRODUCT_METAS[vendor](url)
    except KeyError:
        exit
```

Comment: You allow https but `get_url` always uses http. Is that right?

Comment: yes. you are right. These e-commerce sites do not have problem if the URL is HTTP or HTTPS. Or else in `get_url` I have to check whether `scheme` is `http` or `https`, based on that I have to append HTTP or HTTPS. Just to avoid an `if` block, which I thought unnecessary since these sites do not complain, I thought of going with HTTP. And thank you for going over my code.

Answer (score 3):

The two helper functions feel redundant to me; `'http://'+url` is clear enough as is, and there is an `urlunparse` in `urlparse` module.

My proposal:

```
def get_vendor(url):
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    if not parsed_url.scheme:
        parsed_url = urlparse('http://'+url)

    scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = parsed_url

    if scheme in ['http', 'https'] and netloc in supported_vendors:
        return (netloc, urlunparse((scheme, netloc, path, '','','')))
    else:
        return (None, url)
```

---

To deal with an optional `www.` in front, you could avoid complicating the `get_vendor` function by adding it programmatically to each known URL. Now, if you needed to add a vendor that's only available with or without `www.`, you would only have to change this back how it was and add to that list.

```
supported_vendors = ['flipkart.com', 'homeshop18.com', 'snapdeal.com', 
                     'myntra.com']
supported_vendors += ['www.' + x for x in supported_vendors]
```

Comment: A really much cleaner code! I did not know about urlunparse that's why I was adding HTTP and another helper function. Now with your code, it actually retains the url scheme. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can I do anything about leading `www` ? because of this I have to maintain the list with redundant data (i.e. with and without `www`). I just checked and these e-commerce sites do support without leading `www`. But question should I be removing it? Because once the `get_vendor` function returns `vendor` and `url`, based on that I have to do different actions depending on the `vendor`. I updated the OP, would appreciate if you can have a look again.